# Can someone explain how the root function works in this quick union implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement Quick Union algorithm where ids of the nodes are their root nodes.

id is implemented like this:

```
self.id = []
for i in range(N)
    self.id.append(i)
```

Which stores the index of the nodes 0 to N - 1

This is the code that I can't understand:

```
def root(self, i):
    while(i != self.id[i]):
    i = self.id[i]
    return i
```

What is happening? what is "i"? how does it point to the root node?

I understand the union method:

```
def union(self, p, q):
    i = self.root(p)
    j = self.root(q)
    self.id[i] = j
```

Which means something like: change the id, where the value is root of p, to root of q, right?

Comment: `self.id` is the `id` list shown at the top…? (Which, BTW, could be abbreviated to `id = list(range(N))`.)

Comment: @deceze Yes, self.id is the same id shown at the top, I forgot to add it.I edited it. And the for loop I used instead of range() is just a bad habit I've been trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id[i]` points to the parent of i-th element. If this element is not a root (root `id` points to itself), then code moves to the parent, then to the parent of parent and so on until reaches a root.

Example: we want to find a root of 0-th element

```
i   0   1   2   3
    \/ ----->
id  2   1   1   3
```

`id[0]` is not equal to 0, so this element is leaf, we make a step to it's parent 2

```
i   0   1   2   3
        <---\/
id  2   1   1   3
```

`id[2]` is not equal to 2, so this element is leaf, we make a step to it's parent 1

```
i   0   1   2   3
       \/   
id  2   1   1   3
```

`id[1]` is equal to 1, so we have found root fo the 0-th element

Trees stored in that array:

```
 1          3
 /  
2
\
 0
```

Comment: I still don't get it. What is the relation between i and id[]? Edit: How do does it make a step to parent and stop at the root?

Comment: `i` is index of element. `id[i]` is index of it's parent. In my example there is forest of two trees: 0,1,2 belong to the first tree with root 1, and 3 forms own tree.

Comment: I kind of have some idea what's happening. When i is not id[i] then i is changed to the value of id[i], but I can't understand how this makes i the root node.

Comment: `i` goes to parent and climbs up and up to the root. When it stops - `i`contains root  for **initial** value of `i`. I added picture

Comment: So at the end when `i` is equal to `id[i]`, it's the root node? Why?

Comment: By definition, by id[] nature  - when id[i] contains itself - it is a root. Note that just after creation every element is one-element tree - look at your first code fragment - it fills id[i] with i. Then we insert links and elements join into trees, so id array changes.

Comment: OH! I think I got it, initially the values of `i` and `id` were the same, but when we called `union(p,q)`, the `id[p]` changed to `id[q]` or rather the root node of `p` changed to root node of `q`. So, to point to the root node of `p`, we gotta move to the `id[q]` where index of q is equal to the original index `i`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My example tree might be constructed as union(1,2) then union(0, 2)

Comment: That's right. union(1,2) and union(0,2). Man, this was so weird, I just had to look at the root function w.r.t the union function. Anyways, thank you for your time.